# Nothing happens when I use Firebase Auth (v9) (React Native)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to build an Android/iOS app with authentication.
I tried to use createUserWithEmailAndPassword, unfortunately nothing happens, no user added, and even when I console.log the res, nothing is printed in the console. Also, no error in the console.

So I'm wondering why this happens and how can I do something, if I missed something, to make it work.

I also tried downgrading firebase to v8, which means changing everything, but it was the same problem.

```
// components/signup.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, Alert, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { signup } from '../database/firebase';

export default class Signup extends Component {
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { 
      displayName: '',
      email: '', 
      password: '',
      isLoading: false
    }
  }
  updateInputVal = (val, prop) => {
    const state = this.state;
    state[prop] = val;
    this.setState(state);
  }
  registerUser = () => {
    if(this.state.email === '' && this.state.password === '') {
      Alert.alert('Merci de rentrer toutes vos informations.')
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: true,
      })
      console.log("This is still showing in the console");
      signup(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res); // nothing on the console
        var user = res.user;
        user.updateProfile({
          displayName: this.state.displayName
        })
        console.log('Inscription réussie !')
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          displayName: '',
          email: '', 
          password: ''
        })
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
      })
      .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }))      
    }
  }
```

```
// database/firebase.js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
// config stuff
  };

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export function signup(email, password) {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
}
```

````
// package.json

  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.2",
    "@parse/react-native": "^0.0.1-alpha.18",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "firebase": "^9.8.3",
    "parse": "^3.4.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-web": "^0.18.1"
  },```
````

Comment: Stack Overflow is a notoriously ineffective interactive debugger. If you run this code in the debugger and step through it line by line checking the variables on each line, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: The first line (and the one I want to work) that doesn't do what I expect is ```signup(this.state.email, this.state.password)```

Comment: What does it do? What did you expect it to do instead? --- Also: if you continue stepping through the code from there, does it go into the `then` or into the `catch` block? --- Are there any relevant message showing in the console around the call to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`?

Comment: Managed to fix the error thanks to the catch block, it said "auth/invalid-email". Signing up is good but got another error with the login component (auth/internal-error) but this is unfortunately not the topic here. Thank you !